# UIGestureRecognizer across entire view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to be able to make a gesture recognizer listening for a two finger swipe, anywhere on the screen.

Right now I have a UITableView in a sub-view that scrolls, of course, and it doesn't seem to pick up the UIGestureRecognizer that I set on the view. When you use the two fingers, it just scrolls...

Is there a way to make the entire view, maybe superview, listen for a two finger touch and when it recognizes it, it will instead of scrolling the table view, do what I want it to do?

**EDIT**: Heres my code but this is suposed to be a very general question. I just want to be able to have UIGestureRecognizers across the entire view, the whole thing.

```
navBarTitle.title = @"Crunch";

//opening the menuView from launch

//setup the customtable view as a subview in menuView
SDMenuViewController *mvc = [[[SDMenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SDNestedTableView" bundle:nil] autorelease];
[self addChildViewController:mvc];
[mvc didMoveToParentViewController:self];
[menuView addSubview:mvc.view];

[mvc.view setFrame:CGRectMake(mvc.view.frame.origin.x, mvc.view.frame.origin.y, mvc.view.frame.size.width, mvc.view.frame.size.height + 44)]; //add navBarHeight, for some strage reason

//add swipe down gesture on for the menu

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeClose =[[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(closeMenu)] autorelease];
 swipeClose.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2;
 swipeClose.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp;

 UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeOpen = [[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(openMenu)] autorelease];
 swipeOpen.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2;
 swipeOpen.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown;

for (UIGestureRecognizer* rec in menuView.gestureRecognizers) {
    [rec requireGestureRecognizerToFail:swipeClose];
    [rec requireGestureRecognizerToFail:swipeOpen];
}

for (UIGestureRecognizer* rec in mvc.view.gestureRecognizers) {
    [rec requireGestureRecognizerToFail:swipeClose];
    [rec requireGestureRecognizerToFail:swipeOpen];
}

[mvc.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeClose];
[mvc.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeOpen];

[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeClose];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeOpen];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe I did not explain my question clearly. But for what I was doing this ended up working, and maybe it will help other people in the future:

[Two finger swipe in UIScrollview for iPad application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8711395/two-finger-swipe-in-uiscrollview-for-ipad-application)

Answer (score 2):

you can try to do something like this:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer* p = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(actionPan:)];
p.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2;

for (UIGestureRecognizer* rec in tableView.gestureRecognizers) {
    [rec requireGestureRecognizerToFail:p];
}

[self.view addGestureRecognizer:p];
```

hope that will help

Comment: sure, because it tries to catch a swipe at first. the same thing if you want to catch double tap before the tap your taps would work with some delay until double tap time expires. this is how you pay for it. also you might want to try to use `pan` instead of `swipe` or even touch methods detection methods of `UIView` like `touchesBegan ` and etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
//In view did load        
    [self.view setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    if ([[event touchesForView:self.view] count] > 1) {
        NSLog(@"%d active touches",[[event touchesForView:self.view] count]) ;
 UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeGesture:)];
            swipeGesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp;
            [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeGesture];
  }

}

    -(void)handleSwipeGesture:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *) sender 
    {
        //Gesture detect - swipe up/down , can be recognized direction
        if(sender.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp)
        {
            // do some thing...
        }
    }
```

i Hope this would solve your problem. and in touches enabled make the count equal to 2 or any number of touches.. :) feel free to ask if you have any doubts

Answer (score 1):

Add another view with frame of self.view over self.view like "viewForGesture" and add gesture recognizer on that view like

```
       UIView *viewForGesture = [[ [UIView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame] autorelease];
       [viewForGesture setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
       [self.view addSubview:viewForGesture];
        .
        .
        .
       [viewForGesture addGestureRecognizer:swipeOpen];
       [viewForGesture addGestureRecognizer:swipeClose];
```

Comment: Problem with this, is that is blocks all the other buttons and things. You can't scroll, touch, or anything on the tableview, or anything underneath.

Answer (score 0):

There's two way of making `UIView` detecting `touch`. The approach you defined and want that's `UIGestureRecognizer`, that answer already given by *Ezeki*.
 Another approach you can use to detect `touch` is to override `UITouch` delegates.

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    if(touch.tapCount==2)
    {
        //Do something ... (Here, you can also check for the object which touched.)
    }
}
```

Comment: how would you recognize a swipe using this method?

Comment: @SirKaydian, there's one more method `- (void) touchesMove:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event { }` you can check for the `coords` to detect `swipe`.